# How to add another windows user to MS Dynamics NAV valid user?

Tags: windows, microsoft-dynamics, erp, navision

I installed MS Dynamics NAV from my windows admin account and It's running successfully on admin login. But when I login from another account and start NAV(2016), It shows :

```
you do not have access to microsoft dynamics nav .verify that you have been setup as a valid user in ms dynamics NAV.
```

I can't install NAV setup from my windows account as It don't have permission to install anything.

I am totally new to it, need help.

Comment: What is wrong with answers Google gives you with two first links? [How to add user](https://community.dynamics.com/nav/b/sauravdhyanimicrosoftdynamicsnav/archive/2015/12/10/add-user-to-microsoft-dynamics-nav-2016-database). [RTFM](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd355093.aspx)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Step 1 - You will need the Windows Security ID or SSID

Open powershell and paste the below code

```
$objUser = New-Object System.Security.Principal.NTAccount("YourDomain\Your ID")
$strSID = $objUser.Translate([System.Security.Principal.SecurityIdentifier])
$strSID.Value
```

Replace YourDomain\Your ID with your Your Domain and USER ID.

Run the code and in the output, you will find the SSID.

STEP 2 - ENTER USER Details in NAVISION Database with Roles.

Open SQL Server Management Studio.

In My Case the database that i want to get access is Demo Database NAV (7-1).

Click on New Query and paste below listed command in the query window.

```
USE [DATABASE NAME]
DECLARE @USERSID uniqueidentifier, @WINDOWSSID nvarchar(119), @USERNAME     nvarchar(50), @USERSIDTXT varchar(50)

SELECT NEWID()
SET @USERNAME   = 'YourDomain\Your ID'
SET @USERSID    = NEWID()
SET @USERSIDTXT = CONVERT(VARCHAR(50), @USERSID)
SET @WINDOWSSID = 'Your SSID'

INSERT INTO [dbo].[User]
([User Security ID],[User Name],[Full Name],[State],[Expiry Date], [Windows     Security ID],[Change Password],[License Type],[Authentication Email])
VALUES
(@USERSID,@USERNAME,'',0,'1753-01-01 00:00:00.000',@WINDOWSSID,0,0,'')

INSERT INTO [dbo].[User Property]
([User Security ID],[Password],[Name Identifier],[Authentication Key],    [WebServices Key],[WebServices Key Expiry Date],[Authentication Object ID])
VALUES
(@USERSID,'','','','','1753-01-01 00:00:00.000','')

INSERT INTO [dbo].[Access Control]([User Security ID],[Role ID],[Company     Name])
VALUES
(@USERSID,'SUPER','')
GO
```

Replace
DATABASE NAME - with your database name
YourDomain\Your ID - with your Domain Name & User Name
Your SSID - with SSID as copied in STEP 1

The Query provide SUPER Role to user, if required you can change the Role in the Last part of the query.

Answer (score 0):

**Go to SQL Server Management Studio**

Right click on database you are using , select new query and copy paste below syntax:

```
     delete from [dbo].[User]
```

press F5 and restart. It will help you .

Answer (score 0):

## Quick way option with powershell, you should change some configurations.

## For NAV 2016

```
$appUser = "XXX\XXX"; # User Name
$appUserFullName = "XXXXXxxxXX"; # FullName


$dataSource = "192.168.100.XX";  # SQL SERVER IP
$user = "sa"; # USERNAME
$pwd = "XXxxXX"; # SA Password
$database = "NAVERP"; # Database


$connectionString = "Server=$dataSource;uid=$user; pwd=$pwd;Database=$database;Integrated Security=False;";
$connection = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection;
$connection.ConnectionString = $connectionString;

$objUser = New-Object System.Security.Principal.NTAccount($appUser)
$strSID = $objUser.Translate([System.Security.Principal.SecurityIdentifier])

$sqlCommandText ="
    USE NAVERP
    DECLARE @USERSID uniqueidentifier, @WINDOWSSID nvarchar(119), @USERNAME nvarchar(50), @USERSIDTXT varchar(50), @FullName as varchar(50)

    SELECT NEWID()
    SET @USERNAME   = '$appUser'
    set @FullName   = '$appUserFullName'
    SET @USERSID    = NEWID()
    SET @USERSIDTXT = CONVERT(VARCHAR(50), @USERSID)
    SET @WINDOWSSID = '$strSID'


    INSERT INTO [dbo].[User]
    ([User Security ID],[User Name],[Full Name],[State],[Expiry Date],[Windows Security ID], [Change Password],[License Type],[Authentication Email],[Contact Email])
    VALUES
    (@USERSID,@USERNAME,@FullName,0,'1753-01-01 00:00:00.000',@WINDOWSSID,0,0,'','');

    INSERT INTO [dbo].[User Property]
    ([User Security ID],[Password],[Name Identifier],[Authentication Key],    [WebServices Key],[WebServices Key Expiry Date],[Authentication Object ID])
    VALUES
    (@USERSID,'','','','','1753-01-01 00:00:00.000','');

    INSERT INTO [dbo].[Access Control]([User Security ID],[Role ID],[Company Name],[App ID],Scope)
    VALUES
    (@USERSID,'SUPER','',cast(cast(0 as binary) as uniqueidentifier),0);
    
";

$connection.Open();
$command = $connection.CreateCommand();
$command.CommandText = $sqlCommandText;

$command.ExecuteNonQuery();
$connection.Close();



$sqlCommandText
```